# How do I validate a google access token in Go?

Tags: go, google-api, jwt

From my front end, I am sending a google access token using the function call `gapi.auth.getToken().access_token`, which returns a token of this form:

```
xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I found a useful example from a similar question using the `idtoken` library to validate the token as follows:

```
payload, err := idtoken.Validate(context.Background(), accessToken, os.Getenv("CLIENT_ID"))

if err != nil {
    r.JSON(res, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
    return
}
```

Unfortunately, it returned the error: `idtoken: invalid token, token must have three segments; found 2`

After looking through the documentation for the Validate function, It seems as if it is expecting a JWT signed with either a RS256 or ES256 algorithm, so I tried just that with the following code:

```
secretKey, _ := jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM([]byte(os.Getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")))
token, err := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodRS256, jwt.MapClaims{
    "idtoken": accessToken,
}).SignedString(secretKey)
```

Unfortunately, this too also returned an error: `key is of invalid type`. This error is the same regardless of what type the key is, be it a `string` or `[]byte()`.

Finally, changing the above code to use the HS256 algorithm and the key `[]byte(os.Getenv("CLIENT_SECRET"))` produced the following error:

```
idtoken: audience provided does not match aud claim in the JWT
```

How do I use this library to validate the google access token against my google client id? I'm not sure what other options I have left.

Comment: you mentioned *a token of this form xxxx.xxxxxx....` and got the message *invalid token, token must have three segments; found 2*, so the token is not a JWT. You can't validate it with the JWT functions.

Comment: I made note of that, and then I used the access token as the payload for signing an actual JWT, but I ran into two errors I mentioned above when I tried to validate it. Using HS256, I got `idtoken: audience provided does not match aud claim in the JWT`, and using RS256 or ES256, I got `key is of invalid type`. I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors.

Comment: sorry, can't tell you how to do it right, but at least I can tell you: the secret that you load with `Getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")` is most certainly not a RSA or EC Key. These algorithms require specially calculated keys in certain formats. And regarding the audience error, if you have a JWT, you can inspect it on http://jwt.io and see if there's an `aud` claim in the payload.